# Cannot connect Samba share

Tags: samba, share

I want make two Samba share for two users. I use [this way](https://www.juanmtech.com/samba-file-sharing-raspberry-pi/) but i cant connect to the share. I set password too for pi with "smbpasswd -a ". I enter username as 'pi' and password but it is not connect.

edit:

I followed the steps in the link. But when I try to connect, it returns to the password entry screen again. It is not logging in. I didn't do anything other than that.

Comment: You should provide more details than 'i cant connect'.

Comment: I followed the steps in the link. But when I try to connect, it returns to the password entry screen again. He's not logging in. I didn't do anything other than that.

Comment: Do you see any hints in the log files?

Comment: what are you trying to connect with? another pi? a windows PC? a Mac? a mobile device?

Comment: Sorry for late response. @JaromandaX: I connect from Ubuntu pc. RalfFriedl I cant see anything in /var/log/samba/ log files. I try with Nautilus but it says "There is file Cannot connect Windows share"

Answer (score 1):

From your description, it seems you've set up the `smbpasswd` incorrectly. Enter the command exactly as shown below:

```
smbpasswd -a pi
```

You should then be prompted to enter a password for user `pi`. Type in this password at the prompt, and hit the `Enter` key.

I would use the same password you currently use to log in to your RPi (contrary to the advice given in the tutorial). Also, sometimes it helps to read [another tutorial; you could try this one.](https://github.com/seamusdemora/PiFormulae/blob/master/FileShare.md)